# Google Places API - getQueryPredictions Restrict by Country/City/State?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Below is the getQueryPredictions example given by google

```
service.getQueryPredictions({input: 'pizza near'}, callback);
```

Is there a way to restrict results for a specific country/city/state?

The other function/component has ability to do this

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {  types: ['(cities)'],  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported, for supported request parameters please see the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#QueryAutocompletionRequest).

If you think this would be a useful feature please add a [Places API - Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: I couldn't find a feature request dealing with this specific issue, so I created one here: [Add componentRestrictions property to QueryAutocompletionRequest](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154760267)

Answer (score 26):

Use this similar function (it's a bit more powerfull than getQueryPredictions):

```
getPlacePredictions(
            {
            input: "pizza near",
            types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
            }, 
            callback);
```

Four **types** are supported: 'establishment' for businesses, 'geocode' for addresses, '(regions)' for administrative regions and '(cities)' for localities.

Or, if you want to use geyQueryPredictions(), you can do the following trick (but it's not a good way):

**{input: 'pizza near' + ',AR-M'}**

Where 'AR-M' is the Postcode of ARGENTINA, MENDOZA. (where I live) Just look at your location's postcode.

The, when you show the predictions, do:

```
for (var i = 0, max = predictions.length; i < max; i++) {
    var address = predictions[i].description.replace(/AR-M,/g, '');
        ...
    }
```

Hope that helps.