# Restricting Google places.AutocompleteService() to a country in Angular - Not Working

Tags: google-places-api

I have been trying to use the Google Places api to return autocomplete results that are limited to just a country (in my case, the US), but the service does not seem to be using the componentRestriction property.  I haven't found anyone else having this problem, so I am thinking it is a problem with my code.  Also, I am using angular for the app, but I couldn't see how that would be affecting the web service.

Here is basically what I have:

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="query" ng-keyup="getPredictions(query)">
```

JS:

```
var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

$scope.getPredictions(query){

    var searchObj = {
        input: query,
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
        types: '(cities)'
    };

    autoComplete.getQueryPredictions(searchObj, function(predictions, status) {
        //...
            $scope.response = predictions;                
    });
};
```

The 'types' filter is working, but the componentRestrictions is not.

I also set-up a fiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdalton308/cLtyv803/7/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Places API - getQueryPredictions Restrict by Country/City/State?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620308/google-places-api-getquerypredictions-restrict-by-country-city-state)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteService) `getQueryPredictions()` accepts `QueryAutocompletionRequest` object - which simply does not have `componentRestrictions` property.

So if you want to use the `componentRestrictions` you need to use `getPlacePredictions()` method with accepts `AutocompletionRequest` object.

This should work:

```
autoComplete.getPlacePredictions(searchObj, function(predictions, status) {
    //...
        $scope.response = predictions;                
});
```